# AlertDialog function runs on everypage in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alertdialog

theAlertDialog in this code should run only when the user access the Account page (obviously), but while testing it, it runs on the Account page and all the next pages, and it is even duplicated, i mean when i head from Account page to another page the AlertDialog will be displayed twice

```
    class Account extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
      _AccountState createState() => _AccountState();
}

class _AccountState extends State<Account> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => FirstRun(context));
    return Scaffold(
    //there are alot of widgets here like drawer but all of it works fine
    //i don't think its necessary to write it
    );
  }
FirstRun(BuildContext context) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool first = (prefs.getBool('firstUse'));
print('Pressed $first');
if (first == null) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xaa6b6b6b),
        elevation: 10,
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'first run dialog',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 6,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Container(
                child: MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    prefs.setBool('firstUse', false);
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    print('Pressed $first');
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'ok',
                      ),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it happens because you start showing the alert on `build` method. try to show it on `initState` method of the `Account` widget.

```
class _AccountState extends State<Account> {
  @override
  initState() {
     Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => FirstRun(this.context));
     super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    //there are alot of widgets here like drawer but all of it works fine
    //i don't think its necessary to write it
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

as a work around i call the next page using Navigator.Replace instead of Navigator.push , but i dont think this is a real solution